# How to fetch nested array list from mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongotemplate

```
    {
    "_id" : "575",
    "_class" : "com.spyne.sharing.SpyneShareUserProject",
    "spyneSharePhotoList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "fxLO68XyMR",
            "spyneShareUsers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "chittaranjan@eventila.com",
                    "selectedByClient" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "chittaranjan@gmail.com",
                    "selectedByClient" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "nVpD0KoQAI",
            "spyneShareUsers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "chittaranjan@eventila.com",
                    "selectedByClient" : true
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "Pm0B3Q9Igv",
            "spyneShareUsers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "chittaranjan@gmail.com",
                    "selectedByClient" : true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From this document I want to fetch **spyneShareUsers** list.

Can some one please help me with it,

- top id = **575**
- inner id = **fxLO68XyMR**

I want the list of objects that content **email id** and a **boolean** value.

Please help me to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mongo aggregation pipeline you can collect the document data as you want. Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$spyneSharePhotoList"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "575",
      "spyneSharePhotoList._id": "fxLO68XyMR"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      spyneShareUsers: "$spyneSharePhotoList.spyneShareUsers"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: i am getting ** Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms **

Comment: Have you replaced your collection name here: db.`collection`.aggregate()

Comment: ok thanks, i did the mistake that you have mentioned. can you please look into this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182047/upsert-in-nested-array-of-mongo-db